# Mathematics (Logarithm): Solution to question $h = \text{lg}(n) + 1$

Tags: logarithms

If we are given the  following equation:

$h = \text{lg}(n) + 1$

What is the value of $n$ in terms of $h$?

$n = ?$

Explain how you got to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 1 from both sides
$$h-1 = \ln n$$
Then take an exponent on both sides, since $e^{\ln n} = n$
$$n = e^{h-1}$$
This holds provided $n \in (0,\infty)$